# Need Crypto library for Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I need to use AES encryption and Message Authentication Code MAC in my code. I could not find any crypto library in Arduino standard libraries. I found some available libraries from other links such as this: https://github.com/Cathedrow/Cryptosuite

Can you advise me with the best implementation you know for the AES and HMAC algorithms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MarkT has created a nice port of an AES library.
https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=88890.0

Some folk have also ported Rokkit hash:
https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=226686.0

But if you search the Arduino.cc site, you will find a few different implementations and algorithms.

There is really no better implementation, it either works or it doesn't. You just need to decide whether its footprint and memory usage is acceptable for your situation.

BTW, I found these with a 5-second search of the Arduino site. You seem to have missed the most obvious research locations.